# Infix to postfix conversion

Tags: algorithms

I am somewhat stuck in converting an expression with negative numbers from infix to postfix.

Suppose we have a expression like

a = -b - (-c - d) .

At some places I read that you can parathesize the negative numbers to solve the problem. But if I parathesize them as

a = (-b) - ((-c) - d), then at the beginning of the postfix expression I would get "ab-" which means a-b and is incorrect.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Usually we convert expressions, not assignment statements like $a= -b + 4 - x \dots$. What do you want to convert?

Comment: @fade2black I want to convert the entire statement including assignment. Because that 'a' before the assignment is causing problem for me.

Comment: You could also read [this post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/78081/syntax-directed-translation-definition-and-actions/78082#78082). I provide Ruby code that converts infix expressions into postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonically, we convert from infix to postfix form only expressions. However, you can enhance this by introducing the assignment operator `=` in addition to the standard four binary operators `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`. Just define the conversion as: `a = b`  becomes  `ab=`. So for example, `a = x + 5` becomes `ax5+=`.

As for the negative numbers, you can parenthesize them (as you suggest). For example,  `a = -b + 2` becomes `a(-b)2+=` or just separate each operand or operator by a single space, for example the previous postfix expression can be written as `a -b 2 + =`. This is another example: `derv = -dy/dx + 5*(-x)` becomes `derv(-dy)dx/5(-x)*+=` or `derv -dy dx / 5 -x * + =`.